# multiple if condition in unix

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am trying to run the below logic

```
if [-f $file] && [$variable -lt 1] ; then
  some logic 
else
print "This is wrong"
fi
```

It fails with the following error

`MyScipt.ksh[10]: [-f:  not found`

Where 10th line is the if condition , I have put in .

I have also tried

`if [-f $file && $variable -lt 1] ; then`

which gives the same error.

I know this is a syntax mistake somehwere , but I am not sure , what is the correct syntax when I am using multiple conditions with `&&` in a `if block`

Comment: See http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/find-out-if-file-exists-with-conditional-expressions.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[` is not an operator, it's the name of a program (or a builtin, sometimes).  Use `type [` to check. Regardless, you need to put a space after it so that the command line parser knows what to do:

```
if [ -f $file ]
```

The `&&` operator might not do what you want in this case, either.  You should probably read the [`bash(1)` documentation.](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs)  In this specific case, it seems like what you want is:

```
if [ -f $file -a $variable -lt 1 ]
```

Or in more modern bash syntax:

```
if [[ -f $file && $variable -lt 1 ]]
```

Comment: you won't beleive me when I say this , but I tried exactly the same `if [[ -f $file && $variable -lt 1 ]]`  and created this question because it didn't work (may be the spaces I gave were wrong). But everything since to be working now, once I copy pasted your line. I'll accept your answer as it is helpful.

Comment: If you intend your script to be used elsewhere, don't assume Bash will be available. Learn [POSIX-compliant shell coding](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html) and use a `#!/bin/sh` shebang. Your otherly-shelled brethren will bless you.

Answer (score 2):

The `[` syntax is secretly a program!

```
$ type [
[ is a shell builtin
$ ls -l $(which [)
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 35264 Nov 19 16:25 /usr/bin/[
```

Because of the way the shell parses (technically "lexes") your command line, it sees this:

- **`if`** - keyword
- **`[-f`** - the program `[-f`
- **`$file]`** - A string argument to the `[-f` program, made by the value of `$file` and `]`. If `$file` was "asdf", then this would be `asdf]`

And so forth, down your command. What you need to do is include spaces, which the shell uses to separate the different parts (tokens) of your command:

```
if [ -f "$file" ]; then
```

Now `[` stands on its own, and can be recognized as a command/program. Also, `]` stands on its own as an argument to `[`, otherwise `[` will complain. A couple more notes about this:

- You don't need to put a space before or after `;`, because that is a special separator that the shell recognizes.
- You should always "double quote" $variables because they get expanded before the shell does the lexing. This means that if an unquoted variable contains a space, the shell will see the value as separate tokens, instead of one string.

Using `&&` in an if-test like that isn't the usual way to do it. `[` (also known as `test`) understands `-a` to mean "and," so this does what you intended:

```
if [ -f "$file" -a "$variable" -lt 1 ]; then
```

Answer (score 1):

Use -a in an `if` block to represent AND.
Note the space preceding the -f option.

```
if [ -f $file -a $variable -lt 1] ; then
    some logic 
else
     print "This is wrong"
fi
```

Comment: Hi I tried the same ,I'mw getting the following error `MyScipt.ksh[10]: test: ] missing` . COde I user `if [ -f $file -a $variable -lt 1] ; then`

Comment: @misguided, you also need a space before the closing `]`.  suspectus has also left that out of his answer.

Comment: `-a` has nothing to do with `if`. It's part of the syntax of `[`.